# What vocal effects do these heavy metal bands use for live shows

Tags: effects

I have been trying to look for the vocal effects that singers like Brian Fair of Shadows Fall and Randy Blythe of Lamb of God and other heavy metal singers use, but i cant seem to get an answer to a simple question.

I am looking for the names of the processors or pedals or eqipment they use on their vocals - I know its not dry. If you could help me in this matter it would be greatly appreciated.

I am doing a cover band of metal music and I need to get the gear I need to make it happen.

Comment: I have edited your question as the content was not necessary to ask your question. Please have a look at the faq (linked at the top of the page) to see guidelines for aksing questions here.

Answer (score 3):

I reviewed 4 performance videos of the various artists you have provided including Brian Fair, Randy Blythe, and Hatebreed. I did not observe any vocal effects other than perhaps the standard overly compressed sound as is native to this genre.

I think the common ground for all these vocalists is to yell without restraint into the mic and let the limiters do their business.

In one video about Randy Blythe his producer asks him to run around the block twice to get winded, as per the sound the producer was after. See this video here:

Perhaps the best thing to get his sound is run your ass off.

I realize this is likely seriously lacking in what you are expecting. However, if you might provide links to a specific performance I will give it another go.

Answer (score 3):

As I have been a live vocalist in several metal bands. I'll tell you the secret.

Most metal vocalists do nothing live, save for using the little reverb they provide at most venues. It's all about using your voice correctly, the microphone properly & using the inherent proximity effect when the two combine.

If you're pushing or it "hurts". You're doing it wrong. It should never hurt or be difficult to do.

Melissa Cross offers a DVD series called the "zen of screaming", & if you want to do it like Randy from LOG...this is the chick that taught him.

~Rick --
Lead Vocals --
As Empires Decay

Answer (score 2):

The lead singer of Lamb of God uses almost no effects live - it's a very clean amp setup. That is all done with his voice. Check out [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_growl) for an explanation.

Shadows Fall use some reverb and delay on the vocals, but nothing special there as far as I can tell from the tracks I know.

Do you have specific examples of tracks from each band that have a particular sound you want to emulate?